# how to add quantity with product item in Reducer ADD_TO_CART using React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, shopping-cart, reducers

```
CartReducer.js



export default function cartReducer(state = {cart: [],qty:1 }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case ADD_TO_CART:
         if (state.cart.indexOf(action.product) !== -1) {
              return state   // i want add quantity with increment (qty++)
          }
          return { cart:[...state.cart, action.product] } // send qty with cart
      case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
          return {
               cart: state.cart.filter(id => id !== action.product_id)
             }
       default:
     }
  retrun state;
}
```

i want to pass quantity with product item and if same item clicked multi-time (AddToCart) then increase Quantity (qty++)

Please Help Me...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an action should always have a `type` and a `payload`, where the payload is an object containing your data, in this case the product.

Secondly, the quantity should be a part of every product in your `cart` array, that way you can keep track of every product.

Than, I would do the following:

```js
const { type, payload } = action // extract the type and payload before the switch statement

case ADD_TO_CART: {
  const productId = payload.product.id

  if (state.cart.findIndex(product => product.id === productId) !== -1) {
    const cart = state.cart.reduce((cartAcc, product) => {
      if (product.id === productId) {
        cartAcc.push({ ...product, qty: product.qty++ }) // Increment qty
      } else {
        cartAcc.push(product)
      }

      return cartAcc
    }, [])

    return { ...state, cart }
  }

  return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, { ...payload.product, qty: 0 }] }
}
```

Comment: Not Working, Uncaught TypeError: 20 is not a function  at Array.findIndex (<anonymous>)

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer, I wrote this script quickly and haven't tested it...  findIndex must have a function for comparing and it had only the value, now it should work, but please think about what this code does, not just copy/paste it.

Comment: hurray...  it's Working, Thank You Very much, exactly i want this.
but qty++ not working i changed to qty+1

any way thank you again